# ORACLE PL/SQL Stored Procedure Insert and execute error

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a stored procedure to insert values into the EMPLOYEE TABLE.
When I try and execute the procedure with values it throws up an error. Please could you help? Thank you in advance.

Stored Procedure ----

```
 create or replace PROCEDURE CREATE_EMP

(empid IN EMPLOYEE.EMP_ID%TYPE,
firstname IN EMPLOYEE.FIRST_NAME%TYPE,
surname IN EMPLOYEE.SURNAME%TYPE,
address IN EMPLOYEE.ADDRESS%TYPE,
city IN EMPLOYEE.CITY%TYPE,
county IN EMPLOYEE.COUNTY_STATE%TYPE,
postcode IN EMPLOYEE.POSTCODE_ZIP%TYPE,
country IN EMPLOYEE.COUNTRY%TYPE,
jobtitle IN EMPLOYEE.JOB_TITLE%TYPE,
startdate IN EMPLOYEE.START_DATE%TYPE,
enddate IN EMPLOYEE.END_DATE%TYPE)

 AS 

 BEGIN

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE
VALUES(empid, firstname, surname, address, city, county, postcode, country, jobtitle, startdate, enddate);

END CREATE_EMP;
```

Execute command ---

```
EXECUTE CREATE_EMP(58,'John','Testy','Here Lane','Himble','UK','Skipper',2015/02/02,2017/02/02);
```

Error Message ----

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
EXECUTE CREATE_EMP(58,'John','Testy','Here Lane','Himble','UK','Skipper',2015/02/02,2017/02/02)
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CREATE_EMP'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Table -----

```
EMP_ID  NUMBER(8,0)
FIRST_NAME  VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)
SURNAME VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)
ADDRESS VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
CITY    VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)
COUNTY_STATE    VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)
POSTCODE_ZIP    VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
COUNTRY VARCHAR2(5 BYTE)
JOB_TITLE   VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
START_DATE  DATE
END_DATE    DATE
```

Comment: (1) Oracle errors suggest Oracle so I removed the SQL Server tag.  (2) When using `insert`, list all the columns after the table name.  This won't fix your problem, but it is good practice.

Comment: `2015/02/02` and `2017/02/02` are not **DATE**s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error message says:

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CREATE_EMP'

I've mapped your given arguments to methods required arguments:

```
empid = 58
firstname = 'John'
surname = 'Testy'
address = 'Here Lane'
city = 'Himble'
county
postcode
country = 'UK'
jobtitle = 'Skipper'
startdate = 2015/02/02
enddate = 2017/02/02
```

Since no argument has default value, you simply miss 2 arguments in the call, as error message said.

---

EDIT: I've found the solution:

Execute `CREATE_EMP` in anonymous block. This has worked for me:

```
begin
  CREATE_EMP(58, 'John', 'Testy', 'Here Lane', 'Himble', 'Abc','1225', 'UK', 'Skipper', TO_DATE('2015/02/02','YYYY/MM/DD'), TO_DATE('2017/02/02','YYYY/MM/DD'));
end;
```

This is database creation and `CREATE_EMP` definition :

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE ( 
  EMP_ID  NUMBER(8,0),
  FIRST_NAME  VARCHAR2(30),
  SURNAME VARCHAR2(30),
  ADDRESS VARCHAR2(50),
  CITY    VARCHAR2(30),
  COUNTY_STATE    VARCHAR2(30),
  POSTCODE_ZIP    VARCHAR2(10),
  COUNTRY VARCHAR2(5),
  JOB_TITLE   VARCHAR2(20),
  START_DATE  DATE,
  END_DATE    DATE
);

//

create or replace PROCEDURE CREATE_EMP
(
  empid IN EMPLOYEE.EMP_ID%TYPE,
  firstname IN EMPLOYEE.FIRST_NAME%TYPE,
  surname IN EMPLOYEE.SURNAME%TYPE,
  address IN EMPLOYEE.ADDRESS%TYPE,
  city IN EMPLOYEE.CITY%TYPE,
  county IN EMPLOYEE.COUNTY_STATE%TYPE,
  postcode IN EMPLOYEE.POSTCODE_ZIP%TYPE,
  country IN EMPLOYEE.COUNTRY%TYPE,
  jobtitle IN EMPLOYEE.JOB_TITLE%TYPE,
  startdate IN EMPLOYEE.START_DATE%TYPE,
  enddate IN EMPLOYEE.END_DATE%TYPE)
AS 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE
    (EMP_ID, FIRST_NAME, SURNAME, ADDRESS, CITY, COUNTY_STATE, POSTCODE_ZIP, COUNTRY, JOB_TITLE, START_DATE, END_DATE)
  VALUES
    (empid, firstname, surname, address, city, county, postcode, country, jobtitle, startdate, enddate);
END CREATE_EMP;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your input, I added more but it still throws up the same error message. :/

Comment: I'm sorry that it doesn't help. Can you find column types from your table? I think Lalit's answer shows good way to continue searching for the fix, even if his current form didn't help. I assume it's probably some type mismatch that is not obvious on the first look.

Comment: I've added them in the main text. :)

Answer (score 0):

- Of course, you should **list all the columns after the table name within braces, before values keyword**. And you must **match the columns in the order you are inserting the values**.
- However, the number of values passed to the procedure is not the same as the number of parameters declared.
- Also,

There is an issue with the following:

> startdate IN EMPLOYEE.START_DATE%TYPE,
>
> enddate IN EMPLOYEE.END_DATE%TYPE
>
> 2015/02/02,2017/02/02

So, `2015/02/02` and `2017/02/02` are not DATEs. You are supposed to pass DATEs.

To insert a **DATE** value, always use `TO_DATE` with proper format.

Pass the parameter values using **TO_DATE**:

```
EXECUTE create_emp(58, 'John', 'Testy', 'Here Lane', 'Himble', 'UK', 'Skipper', 
TO_DATE('2015/02/02','YYYY/MM/DD'), TO_DATE('2017/02/02','YYYY/MM/DD'));
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your input but unfortunately it hasn't worked :(

Comment: throws up this error. " Error starting at line : 2 in command -
TO_DATE('2015/02/02','YYYY/MM/DD'), TO_DATE('2017/02/02','YYYY/MM/DD'))
Error report -
Unknown Command"

Answer (score 0):

1. the number of parameters you passed to procedure does not match with the number of parameters in the difination of the procedure (11!=9) (the sequence and datatype of them is also important)
2. don't pass the date datatype as like as you passed, put them inside single qotous and use `to_date` function, i.e: use `to_date('2015/02/02','YYYY/MM/DD')` instead of `2015/02/02`